# Maui Binding with DataTemplate and Custom Control

Tags: c#, maui

I am using DevExpress' DXCollectionView on MainPage.xaml.  I have defined two DataTemplates with a custom control like so:

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MyViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalTemplate">
            <controls:CustomSwipeContainer SwipeCaption="Pin" SwipeCommand="{Binding MyCommand1}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PinnedTemplate">
            <controls:CustomSwipeContainer SwipeCaption="Unpin" SwipeCommand="{Binding MyCommand2}"/>            
        </DataTemplate>
```

The custom control is defined as:

```
<dxcv:SwipeContainer.StartSwipeItems>
    <dxcv:SwipeItem
        x:Name="MyStartSwipeItem"
        Caption="{Binding SwipeCaption}"
        Command="{Binding SwipeCommand}"
        Invoked="StartSwipeItem_Invoked" />
</dxcv:SwipeContainer.StartSwipeItems>
```

The two commands (*MyCommand1* and *MyCommand2*) are defined in *MainPage.cs* while *StartSwipeItem_Invoked* is defined in the custom control.

The SwipeCaption appears as expected.  However, when *StartSwipeItem_Invoked* is executed, the *SwipeCommand* is null.

How can I bind the two commands?

(Being new to MAUI, I am not sure if this is the best approach so I am open to suggestions.)

Comment: Bound commands should be defined in the VM, not the code behind

Comment: ... then if MainPage needs to be told when the command fires, use MessagingCenter Publish/Subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

At first, please let me explain why the issue occurs.

Elements added to ItemTemplate contain your model items in their BindingContext. For example, if your [DXCollectionView](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.DXCollectionView) is bound to a collection of orders, elements in [ItemTemplate](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate) will have an instance of the Order class in their BindingContext. When you add [SwipeContainer](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.SwipeContainer) to ItemTemplate, its BindingContext is also Order.

As far as I understand, you need to change the state of your CustomSwipeContainer control when the SwipeItem is clicked. The simplest solution is to define the IsPinned property in your model class (Order) and create a command in your view model. When the command is executed, set IsPinned for the order passed to the command as a parameter:

```xml
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<dxcv:DXCollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
    <dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <dxcv:SwipeContainer>
                <dxcv:SwipeContainer.StartSwipeItems>
                    <dxcv:SwipeItem Caption="Pin" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestorBindingContext, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainViewModel}}, Path=PinCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </dxcv:SwipeContainer.StartSwipeItems>
                <dxcv:SwipeContainer.ItemView>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout HeightRequest="40">
                        <Ellipse WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" Fill="Green" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="{Binding IsPinned}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding OrderID}" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </dxcv:SwipeContainer.ItemView>
            </dxcv:SwipeContainer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</dxcv:DXCollectionView>
```

In the code snippet above, I use [FindAncestorBindingContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0) binding mode to bind to the MainViewModel's PinCommand property. If you define PinCommand in the order class, you will be able to bind to it using a simple binding.

```cs
public class MainViewModel {
    public ICommand PinCommand {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public MainViewModel() {
        Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
            Orders.Add(new Order() { OrderID = "OD" + i });
        }
        PinCommand = new Command<Order>(PinOrder);
    }
    public void PinOrder(Order orderToPin) {
        orderToPin.IsPinned = true;
    }
}
public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public string OrderID {
        get;
        set;
    }
    bool isPinned;
    public bool IsPinned {
        get {
            return isPinned;
        }
        set {
            isPinned = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

Note that the Order class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to let the binding know when the IsPinned property is changed.

Storing the pinned information at the model level is required to avoid virtualization issues during scrolling.